# Does Rainbow Six Siege lag a lot if you play on Windows via VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, virtualization, rainbow-six-siege

I'm curious to know as I have a Mac and I want to play Rainbow Six Siege via VirtualBox but I don't want it to be a waste if it lags too much.

Comment: Also it should work with GPU enclosure right?

Comment: Gaming on a virtual machine isn't very great. You lose virtually little performance, but in turn that performance isn't very consistent. For linear workloads like encoding video, it's good enough, but for workloads where performance must be constant (like in games), it's awful. Games that are supposedly running at 60 FPS or more feel like they're running below 30 FPS.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off putting windows on your mac alongside than to game with virtual box. So yes, heavy games like Rain Six Siege will not work or be extremely laggy.

Answer (score 0):

I use bootcamp on my MacBook to play r6 but i’ve used an vm before. Playing games on vm is a complete pain to begin with, not just that downloading the game also requires a lot more patience (since your bandwidth is shared with Mac OS also). Overall don’t use vm.

Meanwhile on boot camp you’ll find the best performance you can ever get on an MacBook.

In r6 siege I got 30 FPS max on the lowest setting, 1028x920. But you’ll have to turn on v sync or else you’ll be impossible to see because of the screen tearing.

Specs: mb pro late 2013 13in, i5 4258u iris gpu, 8gb ram